# Erro SyntaxError: Unexpected token < no Chrome

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo problemas com esse código... está dizendo " SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " no console do Google Chrome. Porém não vejo nenhuma "," ou ";" fora do lugar. Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

```
 videojs("video", { "controls": true, 
                   "preload": "metadata", 
                   "poster": "<?= $video->getThumbnail($json); ?>", 
                   textTrackSettings: false, 
                   aspectRatio: '16:9', 
                   fluid: true,
                   html5: { nativeTextTracks: false }, 
                   plugins: { 
                    videoJsResolutionSwitcher: { 
                      default: "high",
                      dynamicLabel: true 
                    }
                  }
                }, function() {
                    this.updateSrc([<?= $video->printSources($json); ?>]);
                    this.on('resolutionchange', function(){
                      console.info('Source changed to %s', this.src());
                    });
                  });
```

Comment: E o que seria esse `$video->printSources($json)`?

Comment: Seria, em php, pra printar um uma string. Código: https://hastebin.com/huxowazipu.php

Comment: Sim, mas qual é o resultado deste código? Aliás, esse código está em um arquivo PHP ou em um arquivo JS?

Comment: Resultado: https://hastebin.com/irekufozen.css
Está em um arquivo .php, dentro de <script>

Comment: E em qual linha deu o erro?

Comment: Ai que está o problema... não há linha de erro, o que o console diz é o seguinte: http://prntscr.com/fdmeo5

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss queria muito saber o que a função `this.updateSrc()` espera receber...

Comment: https://hastebin.com/ecosehunuv.scala

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o php substitui isso por whatever e deixa entre chaves?

Comment: Ele já vem entre chaves, ele deixa entre colchetes

Comment: Foi o que eu quis dizer - eu confundo os dois... :( Você já "hardcoded" essas duas partes do php no código e viu se roda?

Comment: Sim, e dá esse erro...

Comment: Qual é o código JS inteiro (já carregado na página, sem o PHP no meio)?

Comment: É impresso isso na página: https://hastebin.com/awitalezom.js

Comment: Código completo: https://hastebin.com/wigavikibi.xml

Comment: Os arquivos JS em `head` estão todos sendo carregados corretamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é nas URLs:

- http://player.loadplayer.net/assets/js/videojs/plugins/videojs-resolution-switcher.js
- http://player.loadplayer.net/assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
- http://player.loadplayer.net/assets/js/jquery.min.js

Os arquivos não existem no servidor, o caminho delas devem estar errado, essa mensagem de erro:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Porque provavelmente ao tentar carregar é feito download da página de erro que é um HTML e o primeiro caractere encontrado é o `<` na linha:

```
<div class="container not-found">
```

O motor JavaScript tenta fazer o "parser" e encontra o `<` do `<div`, logo em seguida causa o erro. Para resolver corrija as URLs, ou se estiverem corretas então deve ser porque você não fez o upload apropriadamente ou algum nome de pasta ou arquivo esta em letra maiúscula, quando deveriam estar com letras minusculas.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado <3

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente, sua aplicação está esperando uma resposta em JSON, mas está recebendo HTML (provavelmente uma página de erro). Se possível, verifique os logs do backend.

Espero ter ajudado.